# Classification - There is/are

Tags: grammar, verbs, adverbs, syntactic-analysis

What is the official 'name' for the 'there is' / 'there are' construction? Is it a verb phrase or a lexical verb?

I'd say possibly a verb but it must be the most difficult term to Google.

Comment: Anticipatory subject (clause) with existential there. [Joe Carillo](http://josecarilloforum.com/forum/index.php?topic=1734.0) examines the usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the output of the English syntactic rule, transformation, or alternation ***There*-Insertion**.

*There*-insertion takes as input a sentence with one of [a large set of verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/thereins.vbs.html), and generates as output a sentence meaning the same thing, but having a dummy *there* as subject.  The original subject is moved to a position after the first auxiliary verb if there is one, or after one of many locative/existential predicates like *stand* or *arise*.

- *A commotion arose.*    ➞  ***There*** arose a commotion.
- *A giraffe is standing in the shower.*    ➞   ***There*** is a giraffe standing in the shower.

All the verbs that govern *There*-insertion are concerned with (coming into) existence and/or with location. The historic origin of *there* in this construction is the locative distal deictic *there*, and locatives are common in the construction, but dummy *there* is no longer the same word as demonstrative *there*:

- *There's a man **there** looking at you.*
- *There's a man **here** waiting for you.*

As for what name *there is/are* has syntactically, that chunk really doesn't have one. 
*There* is a dummy subject, and *is/are* an auxiliary verb -- though it's not the only verb that governs *There*-Insertion -- and they don't form a constituent; just a subject plus an auxiliary verb. That **is** the kind of structure that invites contraction, though, and that's why *there's* is so common, even with plural subjects -- once a structure has been contracted, it's frozen, and agreement won't work.

The construction is, as I said, the output of a transformation. Some people may call it an existential construction, but it's not the only one such in English, and that has to do with what it **means**, not with its grammar.

Answer (score 4):

This is generally called an **existential clause** with *there* functioning as a kind of dummy subject.

For example, the version without the existential clause of 'There is someone who cares' is 'Someone who cares exists', and it is clear that semantically, 'someone who cares' is the subject.