# Term for "there" support?

Tags: grammar, terminology

I am currently learning German on Duolingo and one of the phrases for translation is "There is oil on the shirts" which in German comes out as "Oil is on the shirts" which works just as well in English. The addition of "there" in the English phrase reminds me of "do" support in questions: "Does he eat?" vs "He eats?" or "Eats he?" in some other languages.

What is the name of the grammatical feature using "there"?

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not/140866#140866

Comment: The rule is called [_There_-Insertion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/197376/15299). It is an alternation rule, governed by [a large set of verbs, mostly locative](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/there-levin.pdf).

Comment: Following the link from @JohnLawler this is the correct answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190328/classification-there-is-are/190345#190345