# Identifying the funtion of "There" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

What part of speech or function does the word **There** have in the following statement?

***There is no quick way to become wealthy.***

I would like to diagram this sentence but am having trouble.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classification - There is/are](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190328/classification-there-is-are) Where Prof Lawler's answer says [*It's the output of the English syntactic rule, transformation, or alternation **There-Insertion** ... As for what name **there is/are** has syntactically, that chunk really doesn't have one.*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190328/classification-there-is-are)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, *there* is known as an expletive (AKA a false subject). Expletives are not considered to be a part of the sentence for diagramming purposes, so the word *there* sits detached and above the top of the main line of the diagram. Search the internet for "how to diagram expletives." You'll turn up several examples.