# What is the use of the word "there" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, parts-of-speech

While working with my brother on his grammar, I saw the sentence:

> **There** were several good reasons for his mistake.

The question in his work was what part of speech is *reasons* (subject), but I am stumped as to what part of speech *there* is.

So, what part of speech is *there* in the above sentence?

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary? You need to show some degree of research.

Comment: In old grammar it is a pronoun, an impersonal pronoun. In new syntax it has various names: try "place keeper."

Comment: "There" is a dummy pronoun; it (not "reasons") is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: *Have you looked it up* The irony is this advice is exactly as useless to Lydia as the collection of responses to her question.

Comment: It's really little different from saying "I looked in the basement.  There were the books I had misplaced."  "There" is a pronoun which generally means "in that place", but in the case of your example it's being used somewhat figuratively, meaning "in that situation".

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/a/190345/15299

Comment: Locative "there" is not a pronoun, but an adverb, though some say it's an intransitive preposition. In the OP's example, it can only be an NP in subject function. Dummy "there" derives historically from the locative "there" of "Put it there", and the like, but has been bleached of its locative meaning and reanalysed as a pronoun. This split can be seen in such examples as "There (pro) is nothing there (adv)". The pronunciation is different, too, with locative "there" rhyming with "dare" and meaning in or at that place, and dummy pronoun "there" pronounced unstressed with a reduced vowel.

Comment: It's an **empty subject**

Answer (score -1):

From elsewhere on the we:

Wikipedia’s article “Syntactic expletive” (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive) calls the word “there” a syntactic expletive, and like Bill J. and Hugh, it also talks about “dummy pronouns” and “place keepers.” But I’m not sure those can be considered parts of speech.

Dictionary.com suggests that the word “there” is sometimes a pronoun “(used to introduce a sentence or clause in which the verb comes before its subject or has no complement): There is no hope.” That seems right to me. The sentence "There is good reason" seems grammatically parallel to "It is no use," where the word "It" seems obviously a pronoun.

Comment: Pronoun is a subclass of noun which certainly is a part of speech. In the OP's example, "There" is a noun phrase in subject function.

Comment: Is there any way to elicit Lydia's reaction upon learning that pronoun is a subclass of noun and that "there" is a noun phrase in subject function? Why, you're nothing but a pack of cards!

Answer (score -3):

It is an adverb. If you isolate the sentence to "were several good reasons for his mistake", you see that you have to describe the verb "were". What were, where were, etc. In this case, it's "there". And because "there" modifies the verb "were", it is an adverb.

Comment: Hello. Eddie. I don't usually downvote answers from new participants, but this is almost certainly wrong (this is almost certainly not the locative usage) and unsupported.

Comment: Adverbial if heavily stressed, as in Shakespeare's Tomorrow and Tomorrow  "There would have been a time for such a word..."