# What topicalizing role does "do" play in "Only now do we have what we need to move forward"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, emphasis, do-support, fronting

In the sentence "Only now do we have what we need to move forward", the word *do* clearly has some emphasizing meaning.

But I would like a more precise understanding. Topicalization and  fronting are somehow involved .

Is *do* turning the verb *have* into the topic? But *do* is not a placeholder in fronted position for the main verb *have*, is it?

What is going on in this sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the sentence
>
> - *Only now do we have what we need to move forward*
>
> the word *do* clearly has some emphasizing meaning.

Let's clear the mud off the sidewalk first.
The final clause is irrelevant, so an equally good example of the construction in question is

- *Only now do we have it.*

which has three syntactic features:

1. fronting of *only now*
2. *Do*-Support to provide an auxiliary *do*
3. subject-auxiliary inversion of *we* and *do*

Notice that the *only* is necessary. If we omit it, the sentence is ungrammatical

- **Now do we have it*

and instead we would say

- *Now we have it*

with fronting of *now*, but no subject-auxiliary inversion and no *Do*-Support. This is because you don't need an auxiliary if you aren't going to do something with it, and ordinary adverb-fronting does not govern subject-auxiliary inversion, so points (2) and (3) above don't apply.

But *only now* is a **negative** adverb of time, meaning that in all the time before now,  the sentence was false, so that we didn't have it. As it happens, when a negative adverb of time, place, or circumstance (one that would negate the whole sentence) is fronted, subject-auxiliary inversion is required, and if there isn't already an auxiliary verb, *Do*-Support is also required, so that's where they come from in this sentence.

It's not true, though, that *do* has any meaning in this sentence, let alone an emphatic one.
What catches your attention is the odd word order -- the

- `Quantifier Adverb` *do* `Pronoun Verb Pronoun` of *Only now do we have it*

instead of just the normal

- `Adverb Pronoun Verb Pronoun` of *Now we have it*.

Use of auxiliary *do* is part of that pattern, but *do* itself has no meaning at all.
Like the *there* of [*There*-Insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/190345/15299) and the *it* of [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299), *do* is a **Dummy**,
put there to fill a slot in the syntax and governed by strict syntactic rules.

The emphasis that you perceive is a result of the constructions, not of any particular word.
Grammar is constructions fitting together, not words on a string.