# there is, there are with personal pronouns

Tags: personal-pronouns

I almost never see "there is/are" used with personal pronouns. Why do they not get along with each other?

1 There is me in this house. 
2 There are them in this town.

I think they are wrong. But why?

However, I can give one example:

Thus, when Christ promises that "where two or three are gathered in His name, **there is He** in the midst of them,"

IS it the case of "there is +personal pronoun" or is it something different?

Comment: Good question. First, the Bible quotation is from a translation, which isn't in Modern English, so it doesn't count. Modern English doesn't do that any more. Second, _there_ is always inserted by a rule (called [_There_-Insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/190345/15299)), and that rule has difficulty applying to personal pronouns because it presupposes existence and location, which is hardly an issue when saying _I_ or _they_. In other words, there's no reason to use it when the subject already presupposes existence; it's irrelevant and therefore has marginal syntactic affordances.

Comment: 'There is me in this house' would most likely be an answer to a question, 'Is there anyone in this house?'

Comment: If you add *just* or *only* after *is* or *are* it would be much more natural. (*There is **just** me in the house.* *There are **only** them in the town.*) As such, this isn't a matter of grammar per se but a simple fact of arbitrary use.

Comment: @user47014 It could also be used when referring to a picture containing the speaker in the house.

Comment: Do you think "There is me on the floor" is OK, if I am describing myself in a picture?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Good question. First, the Bible quotation is from a translation, which isn't in Modern English, so it doesn't count. Modern English doesn't do that any more. Second, *there* is always inserted by a rule (called [*There*-Insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/190345/15299)), and that rule has difficulty applying to personal pronouns because it presupposes existence and location, which is hardly an issue when saying *I* or *they*. In other words, there's no reason to use it when the subject already presupposes existence; it's irrelevant and therefore has marginal syntactic affordances.

Comment: Marginal syntactic affordances is the name of the game.

Answer (score 0):

*Matthew 18:20*

> <sup>***KJV***</sup>  For where two or three are gathered together in my
> name, ***there am I*** in the midst of them.
>
> <sup>***NRS***</sup> For where two or three are gathered in my
> name, ***I am there*** among them."

In the biblical expression used here, whether it contains an inversion (KJV - Early Modern English) or not (NRS - Modern English), ***there*** is used as an adverb and not as a ***dummy subject***, as it is the case in your example, *There is me in this house* (which, I agree, is unusual and may be possible in very particular contexts as indicated in the comments).

I don't speak Hebrew, but the Greek version of this expression [*ἐκεῖ εἰμι* - *there am*] confirms that ***there*** means *in that place* and functions as an adjunct of place. It is emphatic, the sentence could stand without it:

> I am among them (NRS)

But in the KJV version, the omission of *there* will no longer require an inversion:

> I am in the midst of them (KJV)

As for the use of ***there is/are*** with a personal pronoun, it is indeed rare, but not completely non-existent. A wild-card chart in [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20is%20me%2C%20there%20is%20%2A%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cthere%20is%20%2A%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20in%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20of%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20before%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20within%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20no%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20between%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20only%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20is%20about%20me%3B%2Cc0) shows you

1. that the use of ***there is me*** has recently seen a mild increase.
2. that often another word (preposition or adverb) will come between ***there is*** and the personal pronoun.

[image]

You can find it in literature, as a way of introducing a character:

> ***There is me***, and own God-Master. There is Slippers, and Slippers's Own God-Missus. That is all my paws. There is Adar. There is Cookey. (*[The Complete Works of Rudyard Kipling](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-01ODwAAQBAJ&pg=PT4270&dq=%22there%20is%20me%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPjoaspf7xAhVxu3EKHRoJDrAQ6AEwAHoECAkQAg)*)

And you could probably use this expression while describing a photo or a video. This following excerpt seems to be describing a scene in a vivid way:

> But no, instead there is a mere bishop, there is the king, ***there is me*** in a bewitching gown of gray-green silk that shifts colors as I move... ([*The Boleyn Inheritance* by Philippa Gregory](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xZNVDAaxrGIC&pg=PA317&dq=%22there%20is%20me%20in%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih9PvIqv7xAhUGiFwKHRavDRsQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg), Page 317).