# Omission of 'like' in a comparison

Tags: metaphors, comparisons

I started reading the Neuromancer and I'm facing a difficulty, especially in the following excerpt:

> Ratz was tending bar, his prosthetic arm jerking monotonously as he filled a tray of glasses with draft Kirin. He saw Case and smiled, his teeth a webwork of East European steel and brown decay.

I assume the second sentence compares his teeth to a webwork [...], however I don't understand why the 'like' keyword is omitted in this construction.
I'd have expected something like "his teeth were like a webwork [...]".

I haven't found anything about that on Google, any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps because his teeth **were** a webwork of . . . Similarly "He looked at me, his eyes red from rubbing".

Comment: Thanks, but then, why are we omitting "were"?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer but there is a [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190103/omitting-there-in-a-sentence).

Comment: It's called a [*metaphor*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphor).

Comment: @Xyna Good question.  The word that is ‘missing’ is more probably ‘being’:  “..., her teeth <being> a webwork... etc”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here: **grammatical** and **rhetorical/literary**.

**Grammatically,** in

[1] *He saw Case and smiled, h͟i͟s͟ ͟t͟e͟e͟t͟h͟ ͟a͟ ͟w͟e͟b͟w͟o͟r͟k͟ ͟o͟f͟ ͟E͟a͟s͟t͟ ͟E͟u͟r͟o͟p͟e͟a͟n͟ ͟s͟t͟e͟e͟l͟ ͟a͟n͟d͟ ͟b͟r͟o͟w͟n͟ ͟d͟e͟c͟a͟y͟.*

the underlined part is a **supplement** in the form of a **verbless clause** ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), pp 1359-1360).

As was pointed out in the comments, the meaning is the same as if we had

[2] *He saw Case and smiled. His teeth w͟e͟r͟e͟ a webwork of East European steel and brown decay.*

More on the vebless clauses below.

**Rhetorically,** the difference between [1] and [2] on the one hand, and

[3] *He saw Case and smiled, his teeth l͟i͟k͟e͟ a webwork of East European steel and brown decay.*

on the other, is that [3] uses a [simile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile), whereas [1] and [2] use a [metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor).

**More on verbless clauses as supplements,** from CGEL, pp 1359-1360. Note that **supplements** are 'elements which occupy a position in linear 
sequence without being integrated into the syntactic structure of the sentence' (p. 1350).

> (f) Verbless clause
>
> [28] i *The tourists, m͟o͟s͟t͟ ͟o͟f͟ ͟t͟h͟e͟m͟ ͟f͟o͟r͟e͟i͟g͟n͟e͟r͟s͟, had been hoarded onto a cattle truck.*
>  
>           ii *The defendants sat in the dock, t͟h͟e͟i͟r͟ ͟h͟e͟a͟d͟s͟ ͟i͟n͟ ͟t͟h͟e͟i͟r͟ ͟h͟a͟n͟d͟s͟.* 
>          iii *The only household chore men excelled at was - d͟r͟u͟m͟r͟o͟l͟l͟ ͟p͟l͟e͟a͟s͟e͟ - taking out the
>
>               rubbish.*
>
> In [i] the supplement is comparable in function to a relative clause: compare *who were most of them foreigners* (or *most of whom were foreigners*). If the supplement consisted of *foreigners* on its own, it would be an ascriptive NP (noun phrase), like those in [22] (e.g. *Her father, a͟ ͟d͟i͟e͟-͟h͟a͟r͟d͟ ͟c͟o͟n͟s͟e͟r͟v͟a͟t͟i͟v͟e͟, refused to even consider the proposal.*); *most of them*, however, does not function as a modifier in NP structure, so *most of them foreigners* must be analysed as a reduced clause - one which could not stand alone as a sentence. The supplement in [28ii] could likewise not stand alone, but differs in its internal structure in that *their heads* is subject. An equivalent integrated construction would have a modifierwith the form of *with* + verbless clause: *with their heads in their hands*. The supplement in [28iii], by contrast, could stand alone as a sentence. It is simply a fragmentary main clause (with the illocutionary force of a directive) used as an interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was not aware of the verbless clause construction, is there a reason to use this construction instead of one with a verb?

Comment: @Xyna It's just a matter of what 'sounds better' to the writer at that particular instance. It will have to do with such hard-to-define things as how the text 'flows', and perhaps subtle shifts in emphasis.  But none of that is documented, I think. In this case, I can't detect any difference in meaning, but the verbless form flows better, because a comma interrupts the flow less than a period, and also fewer words are needed.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way for underlining texts? See meta, you could post an answer (or a request): https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/how-do-i-underline-in-this-forum

Comment: @mari-lou-a I've looked already, but couldn't find any. It's really a shame, because underlining is used extensively in grammar, and you really want to reserve other kinds of emphasis  (e.g. boldfacing) for other purposes.

Comment: I think our mod, tchrist, knows how to do it, but the problem is that the formatting may not appear on all browsers

Answer (score 1):

There are two slightly different words for comparisons of this kind: *simile* and *metaphor*.  The are easily distinguished.

*Simile* is always introduced by an adjective of comparison (*like*) or an adverb of comparison (*as*).  So we could have:

> The robber swooped down on the lonely cottage **like a wolf on the fold**
>
> He grabbed the money **as quick as lightening.**

But *metaphor* describes a person or thing as if it really were what it is being compared with.

> My nurse is an angel.
>
> Don’t trust that counsellor:  he’s a snake in the grass.

So in your example, the description of the teeth is a vivid metaphorical way of describing the teeth.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is useful to understand the other one :)

Comment: @Xyna You’re welcome, Xyna.  You can even give it. ✅!

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP cannot UV your answer because they do not have enough rep, they can only accept one answer. See: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don’t mind.  I am not looking for credits really.

Comment: @Tuffy Well, I UVd you anyway. :)